# How to define toString method in object literal notation

Tags: javascript

```js
objects = [{
  name: "The Godfather",
  year: 1972
}, {
  name: "Scarface",
  year: 1983
}, {
  name: "The Godfather II",
  year: 1974
}]; // Apoligies f
alert(objects);
```

I want to make it so that alert returns the name of each film, for example by defining a `toString` method for each of the three movie objects. Is there a way to do this inside of the array definition of `objects`, or do I have to create each object separately and push it onto the array? I would prefer the first option, something like this:

```js
objects = [{
  name: "The Godfather",
  year: 1972,
  toString: function {
    return name
  }
}, {
  name: "Scarface",
  year: 1983,
  toString: function {
    return name
  }
}, {
  name: "The Godfather II",
  year: 1974,
  toString: function {
    return name
  }
}];
alert(objects);
```

Comment: Use `function() { return this.name };`

Answer (score 0):

Oluwafemi's solution did the trick:

```
objects = [{name:"The Godfather", year:1972, toString:function(){return this.name}},{name:"Scarface", year:1982, toString:function(){return this.name}},{name:"The Godfather II", year:1974, toString:function(){return this.name}}];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `this.name` to the `toString` function.

```js
objects = [{
  name: "The Godfather",
  year: 1972,
  toString: function() {
    return this.name
  }
}, {
  name: "Scarface",
  year: 1983,
  toString: function() {
    return this.name
  }
}, {
  name: "The Godfather II",
  year: 1974,
  toString: function() {
    return this.name
  }
}];
alert(objects[1].toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `function() { return this.name };`

Better, re-use the same function rather than creating a new function each time.

```
function toString() {
  return this.name;
}

objects = [
  {name:"The Godfather", year:1972, toString: toString}
  {name:"Scarface", year:1983, toString: toString},
  {name:"The Godfather II", year:1974, toString: toString}
];
alert(objects);
```

Much better, write a wrapper function that returns a new object with `toString` attached to the object prototype.

```
function Movie(obj) {
  this.name = obj.name;
  this.year = obj.year;
}

Movie.prototype.toString = function() {
  return this.name;
};

objects = [
  new Movie({name:"The Godfather", year:1972}),
  new Movie({name:"Scarface", year:1983}),
  new Movie({name:"The Godfather II", year:1974}),
];
alert(objects);
```